# Alacritty: run a startup script?

Tags: alacritty

I'm on Windows 10 and trying to run a startup script (vcvars64.bat) to setup the MSVC compiler before using the Alacritty prompt.
I have tried the `-e` switch with the command and also with the `alacritty.yml` `shell:` option, but both options open `Alacritty`, run the command, then exit.

How do I run a script on startup as the first command then continue into `Alacritty`?

Thanks,
Matic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What I ended up with is:**

1. Specify `program: cmd.exe` in Alacritty `alacritty.yml`:

   ```
   shell:
     program: cmd.exe
   ```
2. Create a shortcut to `Alacritty.exe` and place it eg. in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\` (so that it shows up in Windows search).
3. In properties for the shortcut, under `target`, specify:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files\Alacritty\alacritty.exe" --command "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat >/NUL" && bash.exe
   ```

   *Modify Visual Studio path to whatever you have, and which `varsall.bat` you want to use.*

The tricky part was how sensitive `cmd.exe` is regarding quotes. Eg., it does not work for me to specify an absolute path to which `bash.exe` to use, it would fail on the first whitespace in the path no matter how I tried to quote it. So make sure the correct `bash.exe` is first in your `PATH` (open plain `cmd.exe` and run `where bash.exe` to see order). Another solution is of course to create a shortcut to the `bash.exe` of your liking to a place without spaces in its path then specify it's absolute path (tested to work).

Comment: I'm looking for something like this in macOS. Any idea?

Comment: @ranemirusG For *nix systems it isn't as complicated (tools aren't spread around all over the place). In your terminal, just check with `which clang++`, and if it shows up you are good to go (assuming you're not cross-compiling for some exotic cpu).